# Dell studio xps - windows vista unltimate - goes to sleep at random times?

Tags: windows-vista, sleep

My laptop goes to sleep randomly for no reson regardless of what I'm doing.

There is no setting that put the computer to sleep, that I know of. Under the power options in the control panel I set ever option I could find that might set the computer to sleep to "never". The computer had a internal cleaning done eariler this week. The thermal paste was reapplied and was installed correctly, so over heating is not an issue. When it restarts the CPU temp is going between 40 - 60 degrees C.

Anyone have any clue what might be doing that? Possibly a dell tool that I'm not aware of that could be doing so?

Comment: Anyone know what to do?):